# I keep getting an error on RPC's in photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, photon, photon-pun

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator;
    [SerializeField] private string nuke = "nuke";
    public AudioSource nukeSound;

    private PhotonView PV;

    private void Update()
    {
        PV = GetScript.pView;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Hand"))
        {
            if (other.CompareTag("Hand"))
                PV.RPC("RPC_playAnim", RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
                PV.RPC("RPC_sound", RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
            }
        }
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void RPC_sound()
    {
        nukeSound.Play();
    }

    void RPC_playAnim()
    {
        animator.Play(nuke, 0, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

That is my script and the error

[image]

I tried messing around with the photon views with the rpc's and nothing seems to work,

I even tried testing different photon views but it didn't help if someone could help it would be very appreiciated.

Comment: Please include the error as text, not as an image.  Did you try the suggestions presented in the error?

Comment: You forgot to add the `[PunRPC]` attribute on the method.

Comment: what punRPC method it's there

Comment: `void RPC_playAnim()`.  Each RPC method must be decorated with the `PunRPC` attribute.

Comment: I literally have it it's above void RPC_sound().

Comment: I need help understanding please

Comment: @AlexanderMartin exactly.. you only have it for **one** of your rpc methods .. each method needs its own attribute!

Answer (score 0):

As the error is telling you, your method needs to have the attribute `[PunRPC]`.

You have it only on the `RPC_play` method but not on the `RPC_playAnim` the error is referring to!

Each method (or in general member) has and requires its own attribute(s).

```
[PunRPC]
void RPC_sound()
{
    nukeSound.Play();
}

[PunRPC]
void RPC_playAnim()
{
    animator.Play(nuke, 0, 0.0f);
}
```

What happens is basically on compile time photon goes through all types and checks if there are any methods attributed with `[PunRPC]` and if so assigns bakes this method into a dictionary so later via network it just passes on the according key and can thereby find the method on receiver side.

Btw in general to avoid typos I personally prefer to not hard code the names but rather use e.g.

```
PV.RPC(nameof(RPC_playAnim), RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
```

---

Further it could also be that this component is not attached to the same object as `GetScript.pView` which is the other half of the error message.

The component using `PhotonRPC` needs to be actually attached to the same `GameObject` as the `PhotonView` otherwise the receiving client has no chance to find the according component.

Comment: I did that but now it's giving me the "RPC method (on both rpc methods) not found on object with photonView 1001. Implement as non-static. Apply [PunRPC]. Components on children are not found. Return type must be void or IEnumerator (if you enable RunRpcCoroutines). RPCs are a one-way message." are you able to help me with that?

Comment: Well that sounds like this component is not attached to the SE object as `GetScript.pView` ..?

Comment: I fixed it all I had to do was add a photonview to the button